# Escape <% and %> in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, escaping

I have a template engine, which uses `<%` and `%>` for templates, but problem is  ASP.NET WebForms think other about that.

In Razor I can escape `@` symbol just by doubling it — `@@`. How do it in Web Forms?

UPD: HTML escaping not helps — template engine don't want to use `&lt;%` and `%&gt;`, so site just show's them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary solution is creating server-side variables and use like `<%= OPEN %>` and `<%= CLOSE %>`.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found some answers here: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?65377-escape-asp-tags

```
text = "<" & "% CODE %" & ">"


&lt;% CODE %&gt;
```

Comment: Sorry, but doesn't helps. Template engine won't work with HTML entities.